# Matching Values from Multiple Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, string-matching

I only have a basic understanding of coding and hope for your help. I have this js code giving me a true false log for all sausage dog occurrences in the array:

```
var myAnimal = "Sausage Dog";
var arrayAnimal =["Sausage Dog", "Tiger", "Sausage Dog", "Crocodile", "Lion"];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayAnimal.length; i++) {
  if(myAnimal == arrayAnimal[i]) {
     console.log("True");
     } else {
       console.log("False");
     }
}
```

How would I do the same task if `var myAnimal` was an array with multiple strings?

So it would check every animal in `myAnimal` against every animal in var `arrayAnimal` and return a true/false for all occurrences.

Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:
Loop the `myAnimal` array inside the `arrayAnimal` loop - checking them for equality.

```js
var myAnimal =  ["Sausage Dog", "Tiger"];
var arrayAnimal = ["Sausage Dog", "Tiger", "Sausage Dog", "Crocodile", "Lion"];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayAnimal.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < myAnimal.length; j++) {
       if(arrayAnimal[i] == myAnimal[j]) console.log('match');
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful! getting this to a more abstract level - do you also have a solution for this when myAnimal is an array with regular expressions instead of the above mentioned strings?

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary from the `myAniml` array using `Array#reduce` , and then `Array#map` the `arrayAnimal` using the dictionary.

```js
var myAnimal = ["Sausage Dog", "Lion"];
var myAnimalDict = myAnimal.reduce(function(dict, str) {
  dict[str] = true;
  
  return dict;
}, Object.create(null));

var arrayAnimal =["Sausage Dog", "Tiger", "Sausage Dog", "Crocodile", "Lion"];

var result = arrayAnimal.map(function(str) {
  return !!myAnimalDict[str];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer since it's also a working approach. It just takes a little less time then the loop approach above.

Comment: It's actually O(n), and much faster than having a loop inside a loop O(n^2)

Comment: I meant the other way around, my bad. Edited comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myAnimal = ["Sausage Dog", "Tiger", "Sausage", "Crocodile", "Lion"];
var arrayAnimal =["Sausage Dog", "Tiger","Crocodile", "Lion"];
for (var i = 0; i < myAnimal.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arrayAnimal.length; j++) {
        if (myAnimal[i] == arrayAnimal[j]) {
          $('#demo').append("True</br>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While code alone may answer the question, it is always best to provide an explanation and any relevant resources as well.